# ckeditor clone textarea showing but not editable

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I want to use the instance of ckeditor. 
when user click on add more button it will create the instance of ckeditor, but that instance of ckeditor is not editable.
I mean user is not able to enter anything there.

Need help...Thanks in advance :)

```
fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pkz7auLy/
```

Comment: can any one please really need support.

Comment: check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/manektech/47htysb5/1/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use textarea instead of input and then you must set the disabled attribute, check this:

```
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkz7auLy/16/
```

Comment: I thought that was what you were looking for. Please clarify the question.

Comment: i want to enter in all textarea.
in 1st textarea he will enter first option.
in 2nd he will enter second option and so on...

Comment: But your original solution was editable. So where is the problem?

Comment: anyone please still waiting.. :'(

Comment: Sorry, but when I open your fiddle **all** checkboxes are editable. I had to make changes to create a second textbox which is **not editable**, see my answer. So I still don't see what your actual problem is.

Comment: DONE
var upload_count = $('tr').length;
$(tr_object).find('.editors').attr('id', 'ckedi' + upload_count);
CKEDITOR.replace('ckedi' + upload_count);